# Spring : Schedule a task which takes a parameter

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a class with the following function:

```
public class classA{

... 
...

void function_to_be_scheduled(String param){
    ...
    ...
}
}
```

I want to schedule the function using the scheduled-tasks element of the task namespace.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="function_to_be_scheduled" cron="${cron}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

How do i pass the parameter to the function which i want to schedule?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) you cant.

> Notice that the methods to be scheduled must have void returns and
>   must not expect any arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The Spring doc about [scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) says:

> Notice that the methods to be scheduled must have void returns and must not expect any arguments

Since the parameter comes from the Spring config file you can declare a bean (es beanB which wraps beanA) in the spring file, inject the parameter you need in the bean and the schedule the execution of a method of the bean which knows the parameter (it could be a simple wrapper of your beanA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TaskScheduler` and encapsule your logic with a parameter in `Runnable`:

```
@Autowired
private TaskScheduler scheduler;

public void scheduleRules() {
    MyTask task = new MyTaskImpl(someParam);
    // new CronTrigger
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, Duration.ofMinutes(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the only way to do this is to have a façade method that is @Scheduled and knows the default value required. The useful side-effect of this is that you can also provide an API through a @Controller to provide manual triggering with a specific parameter - useful if you need to re-run an activity.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${myChronSchedule}")
public void generateActivities() {

    this.generateActivities(LocalDate.now());

}

public void generateActivities(LocalDate theDate) {
    // do the work
    ...
}
```

If you don't need the façade to be public, there's no reason why it can't be private and no-one is the wiser.

Answer (score -1):

The Task Scheduler did the trick for me

1. First create a configuration class called ThreadPoolTaskScheduler class. Find details [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler)!
2. Then create a class where the magic happens

   ```
   @Component
   public class ThreadPoolTaskSchedulerExample {

   @Autowired
   private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;


        class EmailWatch implements Runnable{

            private String userEmail;


            public EmailWatch(String userEmail){
                this.userEmail = userEmail;
            }


            @Override
            public void run() {
                 System.out.println("This is the email "+ userEmail);
            }
        }


        public void watchEmail(String userEmail)  {

      //refresh watch every minute
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("0 * * ? * *"); 
            taskScheduler.schedule(new EmailWatch(userEmail));
        }
    }
   ```