# Java Spring delay api call

Tags: java, spring, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I have a java web application running on EC2 with Tomcat8.

I have and endpoint which receives a webhook request.

I need to schedule an API call (with some parameters taken from the request) to run in 5 minutes, but return a response right away, without waiting 5 minutes.

What is the easiest way to go about doing this in Java? Is this something that the Timer class could handle?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the Spring TaskScheduler. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499177/creating-spring-framework-task-programmatically

Comment: Can you pass arguments (Like name and email address) to TaskScheduler? According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388540/spring-schedule-a-task-which-takes-a-parameter its not possible.

Comment: Ah I guess I never added that to the question

Comment: You would need to store those values somewhere (a database) and have your task load those when it runs.