# Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

```
@Component
public class SaveProviderStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ProviderController providerController;

    @Autowired
    private AttachmentEmail attachmentEmail;

    String fileDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    String fileDate = (today.minusDays(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM"));
    String fileDate2 = (today.minusMonths(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM"));

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        providerController.saveCards();
    }

    //@Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "26 17 * * * *")
    public void run1(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        attachmentEmail.sendMail1("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail2@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail2("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail3@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report1 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail3("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail4@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report2 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "27 17 * * * *")
    public void run2(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        attachmentEmail.sendMail4("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail5@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report3 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail5("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail6@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report4 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail6("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail7@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report5 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "28 17 * * * *")
    public void run3(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        attachmentEmail.sendMail7("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail8@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report6 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail8("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail9@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report7 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail9("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail10@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report8 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
    }
}
```

My project has a method that starts saving to a .xlsx file. First, I want to separate them so that some files are saved at one time and others at another time. I tried to set up this method to run through Scheduled

```
@Override
@Scheduled(cron = "10 10 * * * *")
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    providerController.saveCards();
}
```

However, I get an error, because in the parameters of the method I have (args), without which this method does not work. How do I set the Scheduler so that my method is called on time?

Comment: Can you show the whole class? So that we know which class is this implementing / extending. Thanks!

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388540/spring-schedule-a-task-which-takes-a-parameter

Comment: @João Dias Hi! Glad you answered again) I have updated my details

Comment: You don't even use that argument in the methods...

Comment: @Selindek That's why I turned here for help ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need those parameters? They are not used by the methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `run1()`, `run2()` and `run3()` you don't need the `ApplicationArguments args` because the only method actually overriding `ApplicationRunner.run(ApplicationArguments args)` method, so just drop them. Additionally, I would keep it simple and simply separate the methods (the one overriding `ApplicationRunner.run(ApplicationArguments args)` method and the one that is scheduled):

```java
@Component
public class SaveProviderStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ProviderController providerController;

    @Autowired
    private AttachmentEmail attachmentEmail;

    String fileDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    String fileDate = (today.minusDays(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM"));
    String fileDate2 = (today.minusMonths(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM"));

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        providerController.saveCards();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "10 10 * * * *")
    public void run() throws Exception {
        providerController.saveCards();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "26 17 * * * *")
    public void run1() throws Exception {
        attachmentEmail.sendMail1("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail2@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail2("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail3@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report1 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail3("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail4@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report2 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "27 17 * * * *")
    public void run2() throws Exception {
        attachmentEmail.sendMail4("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail5@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report3 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail5("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail6@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report4 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail6("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail7@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report5 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "28 17 * * * *")
    public void run3() throws Exception {
        attachmentEmail.sendMail7("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail8@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report6 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail8("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail9@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report7 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
        attachmentEmail.sendMail9("SomeEmail@gmail.com", "SomeEmail10@gmail.com", "List for " + fileDate, " ", "Report8 " + fileDate1 + ".xlsx");
    }
}
```

Comment: As always, thanks dude!) I did as you told me before, but it didn't work for me. It turns out that I did not configure the Scheduled correctly. Everything works now! Thanks again!